# Make html5 video div clickable and go to hyperlink

Tags: html, html5-video

I currently have a video link

```
<video onclick="location.href='/video';" width="320" height="240" controls loop autoplay>
<source src="/static/backgroundremover.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/static/backgroundremover.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<img src="/static/backgroundremover.gif">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But the upper div I have it wrapped in an `<a href>` but each time I click any of the video it just pauses the video instead of going to the hyperlink.

How do I make this when some one clicks on the video have it go to another url, ie `/video`

Comment: Your code is straight loading and playing the video. I don't think you can assign it within an a tag. I believe you will need an overlay that renders at the same position but with a higher z-index.

Comment: @SHenry could you give an example? I tried putting the video in a  <div class="overlay"> with a z index of negative and positive, as well as tried the overlay both in the same div with no success.  It still pauses the video

Comment: You have to position it exactly over the video and have the link match the div size.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of help from the comments, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552902/make-div-overlay-match-video-div-exactly), which in answering I answered this, so I will just go ahead and post it here as well, but the working css and html.

```
#video {     position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; min-height: 100%;
         min-width: 100%; z-index: 9997; }
#overlay { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;
           z-index: 9998; }
#main_container {position: relative; left:0; top:0; }
```

and html

```
<div id="main_container"class="d-none d-md-block">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls loop autoplay>
  <source src="/static/backgroundremover.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/static/backgroundremover.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <img src="/static/backgroundremover.gif">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```