# Make div overlay match video div exactly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html5-video

I'm trying to make a div to overlay this div in bootstrap4

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <br>
    <h2>Remove Video Background</h2>
    <p>Example:</p>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block">
        <video width="320" height="240" controls loop autoplay>
        <source src="/static/backgroundremover.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/static/backgroundremover.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <img src="/static/backgroundremover.gif">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm unsure where to put the new  or how to size it in the css to be the exact same size.

My end goal is to make the entire div clickable as I Asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552666/make-html5-video-div-clickable-and-go-to-hyperlink), and was suggested this as a method to solve it.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-reasons-your-z-index-isnt-working-and-how-to-fix-it-coder-coder-6bc05f103e6c/

Answer (score 0):

There was some weird issues with positioning.  After a bit, I learned that overlays have to be sibling divs, if not it will not work.  There was also issues with the position being absolute on both, one had to be relative and the other absolute.

Here is the final css

```
#video {     position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; min-height: 100%;
         min-width: 100%; z-index: 9997; }
#overlay { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;
           z-index: 9998; }
```

and html

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls loop autoplay>
  <source src="/static/backgroundremover.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/static/backgroundremover.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <img src="/static/backgroundremover.gif">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```